# Delete referring to multiple table doesn't work on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I'm trying to delete from a table, using join from other tables.

My sql is the following:

```
DELETE FROM `threadsread` 
USING `mybb_threads` t
WHERE
threadsread.tid=threads.tid and threadsread.uid in (2111, 2564, 2326, 2510) 
and mybb_threads.fid=30
```

But I get the following error:

> ## 1109 - Unknown table 'mybb_threadsread' in MULTI DELETE

None of those are views, all are real tables. And I could run a select using a similar SQL, without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the following sql:

```
delete  FROM threadsread
USING  threadsread 
 inner join threads
WHERE
threadsread.tid=threads.tid and threadsread.uid in (2111, 2564, 2326, 2510) 
and threads.fid=30
```

Thanks for the help M. of CA

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the below from Mysql.com

> For the first multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the
>   tables listed before the FROM clause are deleted. For the second
>   multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed in
>   the FROM clause (before the USING clause) are deleted. The effect is
>   that you can delete rows from many tables at the same time and have
>   additional tables that are used only for searching:
>
> DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id
>   AND t2.id=t3.id; Or:
>
> DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE
>   t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id; These statements use all three tables
>   when searching for rows to delete, but delete matching rows only from
>   tables t1 and t2.